# How to remove specific entities from a checkbox type in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form in which I want to have checkboxes to add or remove elements from a collection: a `User` which have `Responsability[]`.

I want to show some of the existing `Responsability` in the form but not all of them. I use an attribute called `automatic` to determine if I want to display them or not.

How can I edit my form to do such a thing?

`UserType.php`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom d\'utilisateurice'
            ])
            ->add('responsibilities', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => Responsibility::class,
                // uses the Responsibility.label property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'label',
                'label' => 'Rôles',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choice_attr' => function($responsibility)
                {
                    return [
                        'data-responsibility-description' => $responsibility->getDescription(),
                    ];
                },
            ])
            ->add('submit',SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Changer les informations',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'btn btn-outline-primary float-right'
                ]
            ]);
}
```

`edit.html.twig`:

```
{{ form_start(edit_form, {'attr': {'id': 'form-edit-user'}}) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(edit_form.username) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.username) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(edit_form.responsibilities) }}
        {% for responsibility in edit_form.responsibilities %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_widget(responsibility) }}
                    {{ form_label(responsibility) }}
                    <span class="text-muted responsibility-description">
                        {{ responsibility.vars.attr['data-responsibility-description'] }}
                    </span>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
{{ form_end(edit_form) }}
```

Comment: Is the attribute `automatic` part of the Responsibility-entity and what are the possible values, I guess true/false?

Comment: `autotomatic` is a Responsability attribute and has getter and setter. It's possible values are true or false.

Comment: So, basically you want to only display those Responsibility-entites in your form which have the value set to true and not display any of those with the value false (or maybe null), right?

Comment: I want to only display the Responsibility-entites in the form which have the value set to false, and not display those with the value true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `query_builder` form option as documented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder).

Something like this should work:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
    return $repository
        ->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->where('o.automatic = FALSE');
}
```

Or like this if you prefer having a parameter:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
    return $repository
        ->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->where('o.automatic = :automatic')
        ->setParameter('automatic', false);
}
```